# Problems with writing to a table from a looped stepwise regression

Tags: r, loops, statistics, regression

I have a total of 95 potential predictor variables, I'd like to reduce that number to those variables with more predictive power. My plan thus far has been to write some code to:

- within a loop select 6 random predictors and perform a stepwise regression (direction=both) upon them.
- this loop will continue for 100,000 iterations to ensure that every possible combination is entered.
- The significance of the predictor (from the summary command) will be based on the p values.  Where significant values <0.05 are coded as '1' and >0.05 are '0' for the 6 predictors (or less) which make it through. The predictor name is preserved in the loop output table.

I cannot seem to create a single output table with the 95 columns and write to each individual line using the 6 column ones generated for each iteration of the loop.

So is there any way to add to an array created with:

```
results <- array(NA,c(100000,95))
```

with column names assigned by:

```
colnames(results)<-c(<inputdata>)
```

Comment: I don't really know how this kind o fthing works, but there are a lot more than 100,000 combinations for choose(95,6). You may need to be smarter about combining variables than to take random samples 100,000 times.

Comment: package `MASS` has the `stepAIC` function which may be of interest to you as well: http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html. An example is down towards the bottom...

Comment: You may know what you're doing -- what you're suggesting is a little more complicated than the standard (naive) stepwise approach, but I just can't help reminding you to be **very very careful** with stepwise approaches -- they often have extremely poor predictive capability. Your averaging over many many combinations takes care of some of the arbitrariness/path-dependence of stepwise approaches, but not the fundamental tendency to overfit (I think): http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/stat/stepwise.html

Answer (score 6):

Instead of choosing variables at random, why not use a shrinkage and variable selection method, such as [the lasso or least angle regression](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html). Both will automatically select variables that are most correlated with the outcome.

There is a mature [R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lars/index.html) for this.

Comment: This seems to be by far the best answer to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

aix and Ben Bolker have both made good suggestions.  I'd also recommend `glmnet`, and take a look at the settings for `dfmax` and `pmax`, which allow you to constrain the number of active variables in a model and the total number of variables considered along a particular sequence of models.

Essentially, stepwise regression, one variable at a time, is a little antiquated (oh, when I was a young iterator, doing my first iterations, I did stepwise regression all the time), but it's good to move on to a different methodology entirely.  There are instances where it's still reasonable, but they're few and rather specialized.  All-subsets modeling, however, should be avoided: it simply doesn't scale, and virtually nothing is gained from all of that computational effort.